# Realtime scheduling repeated events in nanoseconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, time, scheduler

I need to create a realtime scheduler in Python that executes a simple function every `n` nanoseconds.

I tried creating a scheduler via the `sched` module and giving `time.time_ns` as `timefunction`, but I get errors when trying to get a delay function to schedule waits finer than in seconds.

Here is the code I am executing:

```
import sched
import time

def scheduledPrint():
    print("ScheduledPrinter!")

def run():
    print("Starting")
    # Create an internal scheduler
    scheduler=sched.scheduler(timefunc=time.monotonic_ns, delayfunc=time.sleep)
    exectime=time.time_ns() + 100;
    schedevent=scheduler.enterabs(exectime, 1, 'scheduledPrint')
    scheduler.run();
    
run()
```

When I run the code above I get the following error

```
    delayfunc(time - now)
OverflowError: timestamp too large to convert to C _PyTime_t
```

What is the finest precision for a Python Scheduler?

Comment: The `scheduler`'s `timefunc` and `delayfunc` *have to use the same time units* - you're trying to mix nanoseconds and seconds here.  I don't think you quite comprehend how short a nanosecond is, anyway - far more than 100 nanoseconds will elapse just setting up the call to `scheduler.run()`, there's no possibility of the execution being on time.

Comment: @jasonharper thank you for the comment, I assure you I know how short a nanosecond is, and in fact I am trying to assess whether or not Python can provide a default scheduler that has the same resolution. If the finest resolution of python's sleep function is a second then I'd potentially only could execute a call per second, 1Hz, that would decree Python as unfit for my test case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe CPython `pytime` uses a 64-bit signed integer to store a "time length". The maximum "allowed" number is thus `9223372036.854775`.

You can validate this using the following:

```
import time
time.sleep(9223372036.854775) # this works
time.sleep(9223372036.854775 + 1) # OverflowError (same with adding 0.1, or 0.01, etc)
```

The latter will result in an `OverflowError`:

```
OverflowError: timestamp too large to convert to C _PyTime_t
```

In your case, `time.time_ns()` returns a value greater than `9223372036.854775`, thus the error.

Regardless, executing events on a nanosecond schedule seems rather ambitious, since the CPU will typically execute the code on a microsecond scale.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I indeed found my mistake was in the use of time_ns() as time function and especially the use of an absolute time instead of a relative time for the enterabs function.